# JavaScript syntax check in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide, syntax-checking

I am developing a RIA application with JavaScript in Eclipse. How can I enable JavaScript syntax check in eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the [Web Tools Platform (WTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) and [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) offer a quite good JavaScript editor with syntax checking. I use the later myself.

Comment: You can also try JSEclipse, JSDT (this last one supports jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [JSEclipse](http://www.interaktonline.com/products/eclipse/jseclipse/overview/) or [JavaScript Editor PlugIn for Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jseditor/)?
If you are developing using ExtJS you can get even intellisense along with syntax check using [spket](http://www.spket.com/).