# Eclipse: can't highlight other js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, ember.js, ide

I've installed the "Web developement tool" for Eclipse. 
I Did this to programm in javascript and to get support by typical IDE features. 
I'm trying to create a web-application and use the framework "emberjs" which comes with some .js files for ember, jquery and handlebars etc.

In my app.js where I want to create Instances of ember.js I don't get higlighting support by Eclipse which would be a pretty good help. Highlighting for Javascript works but I don't get suggestions for methods and classes of other javascript files.

Does anyone know how to set up Eclipse to involve these Files?

Comment: This answer could work for you, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15415629/4453823.

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't help. As already mentioned it works for the default javascript functions like keywords or variables. Is there a special folder-struction you need to tell app.js it should use look into other files?